# Can the application rate "none" be treated as a level in a Two-way Anova?

Tags: anova, interaction, two-way

In my experiment I have 3 types of soil and I fertilised all of them with the same fertiliser at the same application rate. I then sub-divided my 3 soil samples by adding one type of soil amendment at 3 different rates: "none" (i.e. fertiliser only), "rate1" and "rate2". 
My question is: can I treat the amendment rate "none" as a level of amendment in a Two-way Anova?